# How to reach this inequality?

Tags: calculus, inequality, monotone-functions

While I was trying to prove some boundedness properties for the Hardy-maximal operator, it was written that

> If $q>1,  q'=q/(q-1)$, $u$ be a nonincreasing function such that $U(x)=\int_{0}^{x}u(t){\rm d}t,$ and
> \begin{equation*}
> \int_{0}^{\infty }\left( \frac{1}{U(x)}\int_{0}^{x}f(t)u(t){\rm d} t\right)
> ^{q}dx \leq C\int_{0}^{\infty }f^{q}(x)dx,  
> \end{equation*}
> then by substituting $\ f(t)=\chi _{\left( 0,s\right)
> }(t)u^{\frac{1}{q-1}}(t)$, where $s$ is a fixed positive number and $\chi _{\left( 0,s\right)
> }$ is the usual characteristic function, we get that
> $$\left( \frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}u^{q'}(t)dt\right) ^{1/q'}\leq C\left( \frac{1}{x}%
> \int_{0}^{x}u(t)dt\right)\tag1$$

Actually, after making the substitution and making some logic simplifications using the monotonicity of $u(\cdot)$, I reached to the following inequality $$\left( \frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}u^{q/(q-1)}(t)dt\right) ^{q-1}\leq C\left(\int_{0}^{x}\frac{x}{\big(xu(t)\big)^q}dt\right)^{-1},$$
and then get stuck to reach inequality (1).
Any help related to this is very appreciated.

Comment: Could you clarify what is $s$ and $\chi_{0, s}(\cdot)$?

Comment: @ConvXET Done!!

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you reach your inequality? I seem to fail to obtain any pointwise bound.

Comment: @JonasLenz Just substitute $f$, then observe that $\int_{0}^{x}u(t)dt>=xu(x)$ since $u$ is nonincreasing